# Oauth2 timeout with google API

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm using Oauth2 for authentication on Google Calendar API based based on the [introductory quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample)

I'm now running this on a web server and have set the callback port to 9999, which I have also entered in the GCP console.

I get the link in the log file and I am able to authenticate on the server and the application works fine. However, this seems timeout after around 20 mins and when I access the site the log file then gives me another URL to authenticate against. I am creating a calendar widget so once this is live I obviously do not want this to expire and I just want to set this up once.

The StoredCredential file is being created correctly on the server. I am running tomcat 7 so this file is user /usr/share/tomcat7/.credentials/

The app works fine when accessed from different IP addresses before it appears to 'timeout'

The code I am using for authenticating is below. According to the docs, the creation of the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow object with the DataStoreFactory for the FileCredentials should pick up that we have already authenticated.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#data_store) also state that "An access token typically has an expiration date of 1 hour, after which you will get an error if you try to use it. GoogleCredential takes care of automatically 'refreshing' the token, which simply means getting a new access token."

I have also tried setting the timeout manually on the credential object. Google [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/Credential) state that setExpiresInSeconds() "Sets the lifetime in seconds of the access token (for example 3600 for an hour) or null for none." I have tried this both null, LONG.MAX, and 1 year. All of these result in the message "Please open the following address in your browser:" being shown in the logs after a period of about 45 minutes. Using the getExpiresInSeconds() method I can confirm that the timeout was set to my expected value.

The documentation also states that access_type should be set to offline in the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow, which I have shown I am doing below.

```
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = GoogleCalendarService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));


    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();


    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost(REDIRECT_URI).setPort(9999).build()).authorize("user");

    return credential;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this, my refresh token was actually Null. I revoked my token and had to set the approval prompt to be 'force' as below:

```
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .setApprovalPrompt("force")
            .build();
```

After creating the Credential using:

```
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost(REDIRECT_URI).setPort(9999).build()).authorize("user");
```

I was then able to do:

```
credential.getRefreshToken()
```

Which showed that the token was non-null. The expiration time as default seems to be 3600 seconds and when the token has <60s left then the API automatically refreshes this. The app has now been running for 24 hours and the token has been refreshed successfully